# Run spark application on a different version of spark remotely

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera-manager

I have few spark tests that I am running fine remotely through maven on spark 1.6.0 and am using scala. Now I want to run these tests on spark2. The problem is cloudera which by default is using spark 1.6. **Where is cloudera taking this version from and what do I need to do to change the default version of spark ?** Also, spark 1.6 and spark 2 are present on same cluster. Both spark versions are present on top of yarn. The hadoop config files are present on the cluster which I am using to run the tests on the test environment and This is how I am getting spark context.

```
def getSparkContext(hadoopConfiguration: Configuration): SparkContext ={
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("local")     
hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("alice", "/etc/security/keytab/alice.keytab")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
return sc
}
```

Is there any way I can specify the version in the conf files or cloudera itself ?

Comment: i can't understand your question. Especially: _Is there any way I can specify **it** in the conf files[...]?_ What is "it" here?

Comment: @wind Based on this `How do i specify the version ?`, I would say "it" is the spark version.

Comment: A version of Spark can be defined for dependency manager, so for Scala it can be SBT, Maven or Gradle. There is a file in project (build.sbt, pom.xml, build.gradle accordingly) to define dependencies (package name and version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully run it for spark 2.3.0. The problem that I was unable to run it on spark 2.3.0 earlier was because I had added spark-core dependency in pom.xml for version 1.6. That's why no matter what jar location we specified, it by default took spark 1.6(still figuring out why). On changing the library version, I was able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a new Spark Job, there are two places where you have to change the Spark-Version:

1. Set `SPARK_HOME` to the (local) path that contains the correct Spark installation. (Sometimes - especially for minor release changes - the version in `SPARK_HOME` does not have to be 100% correct, although I would recommend to keep things clean.)
2. Inform your cluster where the Spark jars are located. By default, spark-submit will upload the jars in `SPARK_HOME` to your cluster (this is one of the reasons why you should not mix the versions). But you can skip this upload process by hinting the cluster manager to use jars located in the hdfs. As you are using Cloudera, I assume that your cluster manager is Yarn. In this case, either set `spark.yarn.jars` or `spark.yarn.archive` to the path where the jars for the correct Spark version are located. Example: `--conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://server:port/<path to your jars with the desired Spark version>`

In any case you should make sure that the Spark version that you are using at runtime is the same as at compile time. The version you specified in your Maven, Gradle or Sbt configuration should always match the version referenced by `SPARK_HOME` or `spark.yarn.jars`.

Comment: I copied all jars inside /opt/spark2/jars to hdfs and gave the path in spark.yarn.jars. Its still running spark v1.6.0 @werner

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of the output when you call spark-submit? There should be a line where the submit process informs you that it will not upload the spark jars as they are already present in the hdfs in the directory that is specified by `spark.yarn.jars`